# how sugarcrm operate the database ? with active record or something else?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new to sugarcrm, and now I wanna know how it operate the database, but I could not find any sql query in it, did it use active record ? or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

It uses something similar to an ActiveRecord pattern. See more in the Developer Guide...

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/SugarBean

Answer (score 0):

- sugarCRM has it own framework to operate the database (eg. select update delete insert)
  by inherit from sugarbean so let sugar to do it for you.
- the job that you should be done is use Module Builder to create your package and module.